# How can I subtract 2 columns if another column's value is same in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, join

I have 2 data frames, df1 and df2 both having columns 'A', 'count'. I want to join these based on column A and then subtract count from those rows if column is same. So for example:

```
df1
A    count
s1   10
s2    5
s3    3
s4    7

df2
A    count
s1    2
s4    4
```

My final output should be

```
combined
A    count1   count2   change
s1    10        2       8 // count1-count2
s2    5         none    none
s3    3         none    none
s4    7         4        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform an outer merge followed by a calculation:

```
res = pd.merge(df1.rename(columns={'count': 'count1'}),
               df2.rename(columns={'count': 'count2'}), how='outer')\
        .eval('change = count1 - count2')

print(res)

    A  count1  count2  change
0  s1      10     2.0     8.0
1  s2       5     NaN     NaN
2  s3       3     NaN     NaN
3  s4       7     4.0     3.0
```

Comment: Why not `how='left'`?

Comment: @ycx, Because there may be an `A` value in `df2` which isn't in `df1`. It's not clear whether or not this will ever be the case, but the outer join is safer generally.

Comment: @jpp: I get `*** AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'rename'`

Comment: Looks like your `df1` (or `df2`) isn't a dataframe. Check your inputs.

Comment: @jpp: oh yeah sorry, added wrong var name. but my current output has 6 columns as `index A_x  count1 A_y  count2  change` instead of `A  count1  count2  change` and it does not subtract on same column A's value but first 4 rows of any value of A. So first row of df1 gets subtracted from first row of df2 and second row of df1 gets subtracted from second row of df2 and so on.

Comment: @Atihska, I can't replicate on Pandas v0.23 / Python 3.6.5.

Comment: @jpp In that case, what if the values in df1 are NaN because the join key don't exist? How would your calculation work? It goes into negative?

Comment: @ycx, No, it'll give `NaN`. For example, `np.nan - 5` gives `NaN`.

Comment: @jpp Noted. Thanks